Polars: select column based on name defined in another column
I have two dataframes with the following structures:
dfA = pl.DataFrame(
    {
       "year": [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, ...],
       "comp": ["1A", "1A", "1B", "1C", ...]
    }
)

dfB = pl.DataFrame(
   {
       "year": [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, ...],
       "1A": [10, 12, 14, 12, ...],
       "1B": [20, 30, 40, 20, ...],
       "1C": [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
    }
)

what I want is a new column N in dfA that get the value in dfB corresponding to "year" and "comp". In other words, I want to select the column in dfB based on the value in dfA["comp"]. The expected output is something like this:
"year" | "comp" | "N" |
2000 | "1A" | 10 |
2001 | "1A" | 12 |
2002 | "1B" | 40 |
2003 | "1C" | 4  |

I am sure that all the possible values in "comp"  are column names in dfB . Also, the range of "year" in both dataframes are the same.
I tried to join both dataframes and use the value of "comp" to select the target column. Something like:
dfA.join(
  dfB, on="year", how="left"
)
.with_columns(
   pl.col(pl.col("comp")).alias("N")
)

but I don't know how, or if it is possible to convert pl.col("comp") into a valid string for the outer pl.col() .
Note: I can have many possible values for "1A", "1B", etc, so a pl.when().then().otherwise() is not a viable solution.

This question is similar to: Nested polars.col(). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Hericks, the question is indeed similar, but here I am talking about how to combine two different dataframes, instead of just one. Additionally, the best solution, in my opinion, (using unpivot) is not an answer in that question

If you reshape dfB first with .unpivot()
dfB.unpivot(index="year", variable_name="comp", value_name="N")

shape: (12, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ year ┆ comp ┆ N   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2000 ┆ 1A   ┆ 10  │
│ 2001 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2002 ┆ 1A   ┆ 14  │
│ 2003 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2000 ┆ 1B   ┆ 20  │
│ …    ┆ …    ┆ …   │
│ 2003 ┆ 1B   ┆ 20  │
│ 2000 ┆ 1C   ┆ 1   │
│ 2001 ┆ 1C   ┆ 2   │
│ 2002 ┆ 1C   ┆ 3   │
│ 2003 ┆ 1C   ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘

Then you can get the values directly with a left join:
dfA.join(
   dfB.unpivot(index="year", variable_name="comp", value_name="N"),
   on = ["year", "comp"],
   how = "left"
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ year ┆ comp ┆ N   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2000 ┆ 1A   ┆ 10  │
│ 2001 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2002 ┆ 1B   ┆ 40  │
│ 2003 ┆ 1C   ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘


This is the cleanest solution in my case. I didn't know about the unpivot method. Thanks!

You solution is almost complete, you just need to use

pl.when() to create conditional columns
pl.coalesce() to combine them together.

(
    dfA
    .join(dfB, on="year", how="left")
    .select(
        "year", "comp",
        N = pl.coalesce(
            pl.when(pl.col.comp == col).then(pl.col(col))
            for col in dfB.schema if col != "year"
        )
    )
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ year ┆ comp ┆ N   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2000 ┆ 1A   ┆ 10  │
│ 2001 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2002 ┆ 1B   ┆ 40  │
│ 2003 ┆ 1C   ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘

Alternatively, you can reshape dfB with pl.DataFrame.unpivot() to convert dfB from wide format to long
dfB.unpivot(index="year", variable_name="comp", value_name="N")

shape: (12, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ year ┆ comp ┆ N   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2000 ┆ 1A   ┆ 10  │
│ 2001 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2002 ┆ 1A   ┆ 14  │
│ 2003 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2000 ┆ 1B   ┆ 20  │
│ …    ┆ …    ┆ …   │
│ 2003 ┆ 1B   ┆ 20  │
│ 2000 ┆ 1C   ┆ 1   │
│ 2001 ┆ 1C   ┆ 2   │
│ 2002 ┆ 1C   ┆ 3   │
│ 2003 ┆ 1C   ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘

And then pl.DataFrame.join():
dfA.join(
    dfB.unpivot(index="year", variable_name="comp", value_name="N"),
    on=["year","comp"],
    how="left"
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ year ┆ comp ┆ N   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2000 ┆ 1A   ┆ 10  │
│ 2001 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2002 ┆ 1B   ┆ 40  │
│ 2003 ┆ 1C   ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘


import polars as pl
import functools as ft

def col_lookup(index, lookup_cols):
  return ft.reduce(
    lambda last, lc: last.when(pl.col(index) == lc).then(pl.col(lc)),
    lookup_cols, 
    pl.when(False).then(False),
  )


(
  dfa
  .join(dfb, how="left", on="year")
  .select("year", "comp", N=col_lookup("comp", set(dfb.columns) - set(["year"])))
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ year ┆ comp ┆ N   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ str  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 2000 ┆ 1A   ┆ 10  │
│ 2001 ┆ 1A   ┆ 12  │
│ 2002 ┆ 1B   ┆ 40  │
│ 2003 ┆ 1C   ┆ 4   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘

